# ButterKnife not working with Jack?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, butterknife, jack-compiler

I just started a very simple project and tried to use both ButterKnife and Jack compiler, but it seems they do not cope with each other well.

Gradle plugin version: 2.2.0-alpha5

in my module build.gradle I added:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
```

And the error message is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Did I miss something or it's just they are not compatible?

Comment: Up vote just because the question title is great!!!

Answer (score 6):

Version 8.3.0 has just recently been released with support for Jack.

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.3.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.3.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try remove `apply plugin: 'android-apt'` in your app gradle.

As in the readme, it says:

> Note: If you are using the new Jack compiler with version 2.2.0 or newer you do not need the 'android-apt' plugin and can instead replace apt with annotationProcessor when declaring the compiler dependency.

Comment: No, I did never add the android-apt plugin.

Comment: this could help you https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/616

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @isnotmenow 's tip, I tried to change ButterKnife version to 8.1.0 and it works well.
But both 8.2.0 and 8.2.1 complain exceptions, I have post an [an issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/673) on the project page.

Comment: for me it works too is downgrade version of the ButterKnife  to `8.1.0`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Jake Wharton's answer from similar `StackOverflow` post:

> If you are using Jack:
>
> - Omit the 'android-apt' plugin completely.
> - Use `annotationProcessor` for the dependency (instead of `apt`).
>
> I believe you have to be using version 2.2.0 of the Android Gradle
> plugin though instead of 2.1.x (currently the latest is 2.2.0-alpha5).
>
> The Butter Knife documentation will be updated for the next release
> (8.2.0) to include this information.
>
> From: [Butterknife 8.1.0 not working with JDK 1.8 in Android Studio 2.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274453/butterknife-8-1-0-not-working-with-jdk-1-8-in-android-studio-2-1-2)

Check also: http://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/616

Hope it will help