# Move toward j8 and Jack. Gradle sync Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Hello guys I desire to use lamba functions available on Java8, hence I had to apply new toolchain Jack. Unfortunatelly when I did some unexpected error arise. Namely:

> Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForProdDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.
>   I'm using in my project library like

In project I'm using lib like:

- dagger
- RxJava

I know that dagger causes error, however since july dagger2 [has became available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141085/2163045) to use.

I use

- Android Studio 2.1.2
- Gradle Version 2.14.1
- Android Plugin Version
    2.2.0-alpha7

Please look at my gradle

***project/buidl.gradle***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha7'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

***app/build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24  
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0' 

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        jackOptions{
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            versionNameSuffix "_debug"
        }
    }
    productFlavors{
        dev{
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            minSdkVersion 19
        }
    }
    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

ext {
    JUNIT_VERSION = '4.12'
    DAGGER_VERSION = '2.4'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile "junit:junit:$JUNIT_VERSION"
    compile project(path: ':android_mvp')
    // dependency injection
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0' // 2.5 causes error
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    // for new Jack and Jill gradle 2.2.+
    // rx java
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    // RxAndroid providing Android Scheduler
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-joins:0.22.0'
    // view
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    // rest / stream
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:1.29'
    // time
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.3'
}
```

**EDITED**

1. Ok as I've read *Lambdas are currenty not supported in project
   module*, so as you want to use lambdas in project modules - just
   forget.
2. So I've removed my own module and copied whole code into main app module
3. I ended up with successfully gradle build by removing following code lines from *app/build.gradle*

`apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
...
dependency{
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0' // 2.5 causes error
}`

4. However error related with dagger remains, its mean that sometimes project was able to rebuild sometimes its wrote very long stacktrace.

**CONCLUSION**

After 2,5 years after first j8 release lazy Android team is not able to integrate it. 2,5 year in IT is sooo long, so my programing skils became slowly deprecated! I hope they finish until j9 release!

Comment: _"After 2,5 years after first j8 release lazy Android team is not able to integrate it."_ If you want to look at the real reason instead of just calling them lazy, then it's because Android historically has been using a variant of Apache's open-source "Harmony" Java implementation. Harmony was discontinued in 2011 at the point where it supported Java  SE6, which is why Android has been stuck at Java 6 (with a few additions). Starting with Android N, Android will be switching from Harmony to OpenJDK, which should bring it up-to-date.

Comment: I made up your comment, thank you for answer. Nevertheless you just made me more anger, because they had 5,5 year to switch do more appropriate and up-to-date java variant. My whole studies least 5,5 year

Comment: So you are telling me that new compile will now compromise between two java implementations. It is realy big deal? I suppose that both run on the same JVM, where are the differences @Michael

Comment: As for why the switch hasn't happened earlier, I don't know. But given their still-ongoing legal dispute with Oracle over Java licensing I'd guess that Google would be _extremely_ cautious before making these kinds of decisions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Had the same issue. Solved by using built in "annotationProcessor" instead of "apt" plugin

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086683/2282051

remove:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
```

and you already have

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
}
```

It does the same as the 'apt' plugin does.