# Getting unknown property 'classpath' with Jack compiler for Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to compile my project with the next [Jack compiler](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html). I just updated Android Studio to 2.2-Beta and my gradle plugin to 2.14.1. Here's my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects { project ->
    if(project.name.endsWith("-schema")) {
        apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'

        dependencies {
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41'
            jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7'
        }
    }
    }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        instantrunconfig {
            applicationId "ninja.carre.mbta"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.0'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.0'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.0']
    )
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2-b01'
    //https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP
    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile group: 'com.google.transit', name: 'gtfs-realtime-bindings', version: '0.0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile project(':library:android-maps-utils')
}
```

I get the following error when I sync my project.

```
Error:Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForInstantrunconfigDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.
```

Using gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace command to compile:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:540)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForInstantrunconfigDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:62)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at com.neenbedankt.gradle.androidapt.AndroidAptPlugin.configureVariant(AndroidAptPlugin.groovy:64)
        at com.neenbedankt.gradle.androidapt.AndroidAptPlugin$_apply_closure1_closure3.doCall(AndroidAptPlugin.groovy:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$all.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.neenbedankt.gradle.androidapt.AndroidAptPlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(AndroidAptPlugin.groovy:38)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        ... 52 more
```

I've updated gradle and android developer studio to the latest version but I am still having this issue.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try removing the `apply plugin: 'android-apt'` as that's a plugin that wont be needed any longer.

You are not using the *apt* tool, rather the *annotationProcessor* which is built into Gradle v2.2.0 and up.

PS: Make sure you are replacing "apt" with "annotationProcessor" in your dependencies block as well. You probably wont need `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'` either

Comment: How to do if a dependency that requires APT is needed (e.g. squidb)?

Comment: Laurent, APT is nothing else but a plugin (i.e. APT = "annotation processing tool"). This plugin is no longer needed as the new annotationProcessor build step is built into the android gradle build script. In practice, just replace "APT" with "annotationProcessor"

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, after a long time of researching and changes and remaking my code, I found this worked for me.. try removing all google services 9 version compiles in app dependencies and change them for this single line..

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'

when I changed my code to this it just worked perfectly

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTvvK.png)

Comment: **XP** **XP** **XP**